# Dynamic chart name not recognized

Tags: javascript

I want to use dynamic chart names while using `setExtremes` (like chart1, chart2, chart3).

Instead of the below line as `chart1`

```
chart1.yAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max); // which works fine if used
```

I use the below line in order to have a dynamic chart name. But says properties of undefined.

```
'chart' + idconvertedtostr.yAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max); // does not work
```

`'chart' + idconvertedtostr` is not recognized as `'chart1'`. What is wrong here?

My Code:

```
ID = parseInt(elem.getAttribute('id')) 
var idconvertedtostr = ID.toString();
console.log("ID", ID) // returns 1
console.log("join", 'chart' + idconvertedtostr) // returns chart1
'chart' + idconvertedtostr.yAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max); // throws error, not recognized as chart1.setExtremes(min, max)
```

Comment: Which chart library are you using?

Comment: You *can* combine variable names (not like this, but using functions like "eval" or window[...] if its in the global scope) BUT this is a terrible idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Create an *array* of charts and access them like `charts[ID]`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly discourage doing it this way. If anything, you can use an array to store your charts (or better yet, dynamically make it in the array -- for the sake of simplicity, ill do it this way.).

```js
const charts = [
  chart1,
  chart2,
  chart3
]

// then access a chart of an ID:

const ID = 1
// we subtract 1 because of array indexing: array[0] gives the first element
charts[ID - 1] // chart1
```

**Though [this is a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)**, you can also use `window` to get a *global* variable by its name:

```js
window["chart1"] // returns chart1 (the variable)
```

Comment: I have used your first suggestion. Works well. Thank you.